# jquery not working IE7

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

i am using     http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/

with jquery

my code is

```
       <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){     

       $("div.hide1").fadeTo("slow", 0.13);
        $("div.hide1").fadeTo("slow", 1);

        $('.caption').cycle({
    fx:      'fade', 
        speedIn:  2500, 
        speedOut: 500, 
         sync:     0, 
         timeout: 10000,
     delay:0,
     });
       </script>
```

div for that like this...

```
       <div class="caption" style=" position:absolute; margin-top:0px">
   <img src="cap/img1.png" />
   <img src="cap/img2.png" />
   <img src="cap/img3.png" />
   <img src="cap/img4.png" />
   <img src="cap/img5.png" />
   <img src="cap/img6.png" />
    </div>
```

and include file is like this.

this work fine for Firefox, Safari but not working with Internet Explorer 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you specify an object in json, don't put a comma after the last element.

e.g. the following doesn't work in IE:

```
obj = {
  "e1": 1,
  "e2": 2, // note the comma here
   }
```

This should work:

```
obj = {
  "e1": 1,
  "e2": 2 // no comma
   }
```

In your code, you have `delay:0,` I believe that's where the problem is; just remove that comma

Comment: Good call. FF (and perhaps other browsers) will gladly (but incorrectly) accept the trailing comma. IE6-8 (and perhaps more) will not.

Comment: hehe, I've been bit by this before (a lot, actually).

Comment: Most languages allow such construct. I guess IE is the exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try <script type="text/javascript"> instead of <script>.
```

Also, look at IE's error console to see if there are any js errors.

Does it work in IE8 or IE6 or even Opera/Safari/Chrome?